# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11, powermock, powermockito

I am upgrading my spring boot application from jdk8 to 11.
I am facing issue while running the test cases **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder**.

and we are using powermock in the test cases to mock the static methods. Do we have any other option to solve this issue with jdk11. Can you please suggest me the solution.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder

```
at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:126)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:54)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:38)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.<init>(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:64)
at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:86)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:161)
at org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder.build(RestTemplateBuilder.java:589)
```

Comment: check this issue already resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception